# VS2008 Toolbox Controls Repeated

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

I'm not really sure why but my VS2008 toolbox controls (Data, Validation, Navigation, Login & Webparts) are displaying multiple times.  Does anyone know how to correct the issue?  I'm still using XP if that has any bearing on the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem with my menu items.  Everything under Data is repeated at least twice and sometimes 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You might try devenv /setup or devenv /resetsettings.